How to fix the NaNs in R?
I have a data frame as:
library(igraph)
mygraph<-graph(edges=c(2,1,4,1,4,3,5,2,5,4,7,3,7,5,8,4,8,7),n=8)
E(mygraph)$weight<-c(0.98,0.57,0.86,0.57,0.94,0.68,0.76,0.57,0.86)
mygraph<- set_edge_attr(mygraph,"weight",index=E(mygraph),c(0.98,0.57,0.86,0.57,0.94,0.68,0.76,0.57,0.86))
closenessmygraph<-closeness(mygraph,mode="in")
closenessmygraph1<-closeness(mygraph,mode="out")
closenessmygraph2<-closeness(mygraph,mode="all")
betweennessmygraph<-betweenness(mygraph,normalized=TRUE)
plot(mygraph)

the values for "closenessmygraph" are
(0.1545595 0.2444988 0.2096436 0.3115265 0.4201681       NaN 1.1627907       NaN)
the coding is for analysisng the vulnerability for 8 tanks.how can i fix the NaNs? and change them to a number as like as othes.

Those nodes have no incoming edges, so how can they have a incoming closeness measure?

The igraph documentation clearly explains when and why closeness() returns NaN. Think carefully about whether closeness centrality is appropriate for your use case. Keep in mind that your graph is disconnected, and that classic closeness is defined only for connected graphs. By default, igraph uses only vertices reachable from vertex v to compute the closeness of v.


Closeness is as a measure of the number of steps required to access every other node, conditional on the specified "mode" (in, out, or both).
As shown in the figure, for nodes 6 and 8, there are no other nodes that are directed towards them. Hence, the closeness (for mode="in") cannot be computed. Similarly, nodes 1, 3, and 6 have no outgoing edges, hence their "out" closeness measures cannot be computed.
cbind(cin=closenessmygraph, cout=closenessmygraph1, call=closenessmygraph2)
           cin      cout      call
[1,] 0.1545595       NaN 0.1310616
[2,] 0.2444988 1.0204082 0.1179245
[3,] 0.2096436       NaN 0.1273885
[4,] 0.3115265 0.6993007 0.1700680
[5,] 0.4201681 0.2074689 0.1485884
[6,]       NaN       NaN       NaN
[7,] 1.1627907 0.1483680 0.1416431
[8,]       NaN 0.1280410 0.1317523

